# Can we use continuous variables instead of binary variables in this NLP problem?

Tags: nonlinear-programming, binary-variable, logical-constraints, minlp, continuous-optimization

The following problem is defined with binary variables $a_{i1}, a_{i2}, a_{i3}, k_1$ and $k_2$.
Is it possible to avoid binary variables and to only work with continuous variables? How would we ought to adjust the constraints then?

**Variables**

$a_{i1}, a_{i2}, a_{i3} \in \{0, 1\}$ and initialized to $0$,

$0 \le x_1, x_2, x_3 \lt 1$,

$b_1, b_2 \in [0, 1]$

$k_{i1}, k_{i2} \in \{0, 1\}$ and initialized to $0$,

$z_i$

**Constants**

$M = 10$.

**Objective function**

$$\min_{x_1, x_2, x_3, b_1, b_2} f(D_i, P_i, z_i)$$

**Constraints**

- $z_i = a_{i1}x_1 + a_{i2}x_2 +a_{i3}x_3$
- $b_1-c_i \le a_{i1}M$
- $c_i -b_2 \le a_{i3}M$
- $a_{i1}+a_{i2}+a_{i3} = 1$
- $c_i-b_1 \le Mk_{i1}$
- $b_2 - c_i \le Mk_{i2}$
- $k_{i1}+ k_{i2} - 1 \le a_{i2}$
- $\sum_{i=1}^n D_iz_i = \beta \sum_{i=1}^n D_i$

Comment: Yes, binaries can be replaced by NLP by continuous variables, but it's not necessarily a good idea, and usually is a bad idea.  Binary variable b can be declared continuous by adding the constraint $b(b-1) = 0$. Continuous yes, well behaved, probably not.  Sort of a not good way of writing a complementarity constraint. General integer variables, for example, integer  x in range of 0 to 3 can be replaced by continuous x with constraint  $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = 0$. Again, not usually a good idea. There might be lots of local minima.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone interesting! Thanks!

Comment: Please confirm whether you really want $k_1$ and $k_2$ and not instead $k_{i1}$ and $k_{i2}$.  What you have now forces $k_1=1$ if $c_i > b_1$ for at least one $i$, and $k_2=1$ if $c_i < b_2$ for at least one (possibly different) $i$.

Comment: @RobPratt yes, indeed, edited that!

Comment: Does your NLP solver accept if-then-else expressions that involve decision variables?

Comment: No it doesn’t…at least not in the objective function. You mean in the constraints? I’m using ipopt for the moment, I don’t know if you have any experience with it ?

Comment: @RobPratt My original problem had an if then else expression in the objective function but that wasn’t allowed by the solver. Hence the rewrite with these binary variables.

Comment: @Steven01123581321 can you consider using a solver that supports binary variables? For example Bonmin, which actually relies on IpOpt to solve NLP subproblems

Comment: @fontanf I switched to SCIP now…normally this solver should accept binary variables.

Comment: Indeed, if you have the analytic expression of your problem, you can even use a global solver like SCIP

Comment: @fontanf what do you mean exactly with the analytic expression of my problem ?

Comment: I mean that your function $f$ is not a black-box oracle (a simulator, or another optimization problem for example)

Comment: @fontanf when using the scip solver, it keeps on running, so it gets stuck in the problem. I tried it on a relatively simple problem and I get the same behavior. However, when using a very simple problem, it works fine. Any experiencies with this behavior of SCIP ? Is BONMIN an altnerative solver for this kind of problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141047/discussion-between-fontanf-and-steven01123581321).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, binaries can be replaced by NLP using continuous variables. But it's not necessarily a good idea, and is usually is a bad idea. If it were a good idea, there probably wouldn't be MINLP solvers.

Binary variable $b$ can be declared continuous by adding the constraint $b(b−1)=0$. Continuous yes. Well behaved, probably not. It's basically a non-nice way of writing a complementarity constraint, and inherits the challenges of such constraints.

General integer variables, for example, integer x in range of 0 to 3 can be replaced by continuous x with constraint $x(x−1)(x−2)(x−3) = 0$. Again, not usually a good idea.

The reformulation of binary or integer to continuous as above, results in a non-convex optimization problem. The original problem formulation having binary or integer variables, would not be convex, but its continuous relaxation might be. The reformulated problem is not convex.

For binary or general integer variable, there might be at lease one local minimum associated with every integer value (which would be 2 in the case of binary). If there are multiple binary or integer variables, there may be at least one local minimum for every integer combination (if all binary, then $2^n$ such combinations, where n is number of binaries).

Answer (score 4):

You can relax integrality of $a_{i2}.$ Due to the "big M" constraints, I do not believe you can relax integrality of the other binary variables. It's a bit hard to be sure, since you did not indicate what the $c_i$ are and whether $f()$ is increasing, decreasing or not montonic in its arguments.

Comment: I'm working with a solver that doesn't work with binary variables and make them continuous directly. Can we add a constraint to enforce these continuous variables to be either 1 or zero?

Comment: No, you cannot, at least not while staying within the confines of linear (or convex quadratic) constraints.